# Deadlock using std::thread and std::condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable, stdthread

I'm investigating an issue where my worker thread deadlocks when I try to stop it.

Here's the minimal version that has the problem:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class Worker
{
private:
    std::atomic<bool>       m_running;
    std::condition_variable m_cond;
    std::mutex              m_mutex;
    std::function<void()>   m_workItem;
    std::thread             m_thread;

public:
    Worker() :
        m_running(true),
        m_thread(std::bind(&Worker::DoWork, this))
    {

    }

    ~Worker()
    {
        Stop();
        m_thread.join();
    }

    bool QueueWork(std::function<void()> item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> padlock(m_mutex);

        if (m_workItem)
        {
            return false;
        }

        m_workItem = item;
        padlock.unlock();
        m_cond.notify_all();
        return true;
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        bool expected = true;
        if (m_running.compare_exchange_strong(expected, false))
        {
            m_cond.notify_all();
        }
    }

private:
    void DoWork() noexcept
    {
        while (m_running)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> padlock(m_mutex);
            m_cond.wait(padlock,
                [this]
                ()
                {
                    return !m_running || m_workItem;
                });
            if (m_workItem)
            {
                decltype(m_workItem) workItem;
                std::swap(m_workItem, workItem);
                padlock.unlock();
                workItem();
            }
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start." << std::endl;

    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Worker>> workers;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            workers.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Worker>(new Worker()));
        }

        workers[0]->QueueWork(
            []()
            {
                std::cout << "Work item" << std::endl;
            });

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));

        for (auto & worker : workers)
        {
            worker->Stop();
        }
        for (auto & worker : workers)
        {
            worker.reset();
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Stop." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that when calling `Worker::Stop()` from the host thread, `Worker::m_running` is set to `false`, and `notify_all()` is called on `Worker::m_cond`. The worker thread wakes up from its `m_cond.wait()`, checks `m_running` and breaks out, exiting the thread function.

Sometimes, however, this deadlocks. The worker thread wakes up, sees that `m_running` is `true` (how is that possible?) and goes back to `wait()`. There's no additional call to `m_cond.notify_all()` so the thread ends up in a deadlocked state.

I spawn 10 `Worker` objects in this code. I don't think it has anything to do with the number of threads, but to be able to trigger the race condition (if that's what it is), I needed more threads.

What is wrong with the code?

Running gcc:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Compiling using:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic test.cpp -lpthread
```

Edit:
Changed the order of `Worker`'s private members. `m_thread` is now last. Still the same problem.

Comment: This is not a deadlock. You can't have a deadlock without two locks. It is a lock protocol problem.

Comment: I was actually wondering about that. Is "Lock protocol" the right/a good term for this?

Comment: @EJP There are here both a `mutex` and an `atomic`, which, in principle, is enough for a deadlock, no?

Comment: `m_thread(std::bind(&Worker::DoWork, this))` is buggy, because you're  creating a thread which starts immediately and which accesses the other member variables, such as `m_cond`, `m_mutex`, `m_workItem` which has NOT created yet, as they're declared **after** `m_thread`. So I'd suggest you to declare `m_thread` after ALL member variables.

Comment: And also, you should pass `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread` to the compiler, as `-pthread` does many other *necessary* things in addition to the work done by `-lpthread`. Please do explore the difference between `-pthread` and `-lpthread`.

Comment: @Nawaz you're right, but it was - unfortunately - not the issue. Btw, my production code did not have this error.

Comment: @anorm: That is buggy, and as long as it is there, you cannot reasonably analyse rest of the program.

Comment: I know and I've updated the question. I'm currently trying out the -pthread option, waiting for it to "deadlock"

Comment: FYI, Parallel Studio Inspector shows "Uninitialized Memory Access" error after -  workers.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Worker>(new Worker()));

Comment: You don't have mutex lock in `Stop()`. This causes race.

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that prevents this sequence: worker wakes up (possibly spuriously) -> worker checks `m_running` and sees `true` -> host calls `Stop()`, sets `m_running` to `false` and calls `notify_all()` -> worker begins waiting on the condition variable and misses the notification.

Comment: @anorm - "...to be able to trigger the race condition (if that's what it is), I needed more threads." - How many? I am not able to reproduce deadlock.